# R - performing descriptive statistics on data when it falls under two situations

Tags: r

Apologies if this is unclear. Say I have a dataframe as such:

```
ID TIME  AMOUNTSPENT
01 12:34 50
01 14:37 100
02 12:40 25
03 10:10 50
01 14:35 25
```

And I would like to generate a lot of features. Specifically based on the TIME and the aspects such as the mean per hour for each unique ID. This would typically generate 24 columns for each hour in the day. So the resulting data frame would be something as such:

```
ID HOUR12MEANSPEND  HOUR13MEANSPEND HOUR14MEANSPEND 
01     37.5               0               100
```

I understand this is a complex problem to explain, even some tips on how to begin this would be massively helped!

Comment: I think your example output is not what would be expected from your example input? For example, mean per hour for ID 01 during hour 14 would be (100 + 25) / 2 = 62.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `dplyr` and `reshape2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df %>%
 #grouping - only by the hour
 group_by(ID, TIME = substr(TIME, 1, 2)) %>%
 #summarise
 summarise(averagespend = mean(AMOUNTSPENT)) %>%
 #cast time in columns
 dcast(ID ~ TIME, value.var = 'averagespend')
```

Output:

```
  ID 10 12   14
1  1 NA 50 62.5
2  2 NA 25   NA
3  3 50 NA   NA
```

Data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), TIME = structure(c(2L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("10:10", "12:34", "12:40", "14:35", 
"14:37"), class = "factor"), AMOUNTSPENT = c(50L, 100L, 25L, 
50L, 25L)), .Names = c("ID", "TIME", "AMOUNTSPENT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Excellent, I'm giving this a try in a moment. I've not used the "substr" function before, what does the " 1, 2" refer to in that statement? just so I have better idea on what's going on.

Comment: `substr` substrings a text and in this case it takes the first two characters of the TIME i.e. the full hour. You can see `?substr` for details.

Comment: Great thanks! One last thing, might be a stupid one, but what's the syntax for using the "dcast" to add the new information into a new dataframe?

Comment: The one I am using here: `ID ~ TIME` will have the ID as the first column and TIME as the rest. Check `?dcast`. Also check [this](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html).

Comment: I get an error when trying to use the statement: newdf <- data.frame(dcast(ID ~ TIME, value.var = 'averagespend')) How do I have the output into a new dataframe instead of just outputting into the command line?

Comment: The way you do it in your code i.e. using `<-`. Also, you don't need to use data.frame as dcast creates a data.frame anyway. If the error persists it's probably best to post another question to show what the error is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138543/discussion-between-jkay96-and-lyzander).